# Php 8 over php 7.4

Tags: php, php7

Resolved after using

```
    sudo apt install php8.0-fpm
    a2enconf php8.1-fpm
```

Original post:

I have Ubuntu 20.04.4
Firstly I've installed php 7.4 but after a couple of day php 8
in Linux command line the "php -v" return PHP 8.1.8
but in the webpage the phpinfo return PHP Version 7.4.30

Please teach me how to use PHP 8 over PHP 7.4 !
THANKS!

LE
even after using a2dismod and a2enmod commands and disabled 7.4 and enabled 8.1 in the webserver appears 7.4 :(

Comment: What webserver are you using?

Comment: I have Apache 2.0

Comment: PHP in the web server _can_ use a different PHP version from your `php -a` command line. The command line version is selected with `sudo update-alternatives --config php`. What Apache uses is governed by the `a2dismod` and `a2enmod` commands.

Comment: with sudo update-alternatives --config php -> There are 3 choices for the alternative php (providing /usr/bin/php).

  Selection    Path             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/php8.1   81        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/php7.4   74        manual mode
* 2            /usr/bin/php8.0   80        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/php8.1   81        manual mode

Comment: even if it it selected 8.1 I can use only 7.4 :(

Comment: I've tried a2dismod and a2enmod

Comment: disabled 7.4 and enabled 8.1 but in the web the phpinfo still report 7.4

Comment: Why don’t you just uninstall 7.4 if you’re not going to use it?

Comment: hi again! is it safe to uninstall 7.4? how can be done?

Comment: I've noticed that in my php foder I have a lot of folders as 5.6 / 7.0 / 7.1 / 7.2 / 7.3 / 7.4 / 8.0 / 8.1 ... when updating my system I saw that there is updating 7.4 / 8.0 /8.1